# Only Index.html file working other nav bar menu link not working after uploading to cpanel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cpanel, hadoop-yarn, yarn-lock.json

I tried deploying a website to cpanel after writing the code on VS CODE. I tried yarn run build and i got a dist folder but noticed index.html file was the only html file that build also having index.css and index.js in my dist file while other file components like like product.html, about.html, contact.html and other next js files isnt building. On my Navigation menu my Products | ABout | Contact keeps bringing 404 error after deploying to cpanel.
[after yarn building image showing the file properties after building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JTRa.jpg)

My other files before building
[My Files without the dist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xKwR.jpg) 
[File 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M81lC.jpg)

I was expecting to all navigation menu like Products | About | Contact Us displaying after clicking on the nav link instead of showing 404 error also expecting other properties of the nav bar menu and it react components built into the dist file after running yarn run build. Please i need professional help

Here is an illustration on local host using image
Products page on local host
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQe4p.jpg)

About page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccrFb.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.